# If webBrowser URL equals a certian link, change it

Tags: c#, web-applications

I'm trying to create something that when the webBrowser lands on a certain URL, such as www.badsite.com, it takes the person to www.goodsite.com. My idealistic code would be :

```
if (webBrowser1.URL == "www.givingyouavirus.com" )
{

webBrowser1.Navigate("www.virusfreesite.com")

}
```

Something to that extent, and it needs to remain in the browser with no registry editing (but if theres no other way, then that'll be fine).

Comment: if only all websites were that obvious

Comment: hadn't noticed the strings till your comment, haha

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), creating such a rule is pretty straightforward! (some examples [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module))